# Select value field out of possible similar key names

Tags: jq

I have a pom.json with a bug in it:

```
{
        "Components": [
                {
                        "ARTIFACTID": "good artifact",
                        "BuildJobDate": "2020-01-20T16:39:50"
                },
                {
                        "ARTIFACT_ID": "bad artifact",
                        "BuildJobDate": "'2021-11-29T17:23:39'"
                },
                {
                        "ARTIFACTID": "another good artifact",
                        "BuildJobDate": "2022-01-26T21:18:20"
                }
        ]
}
```

in my install script I collect all `ARTIFACTID`:

```
local -ra artifacts=( $(jq -r '.Components | .[].ARTIFACTID' "$manifest") )
```

tried to fix it by `.[] | {ARTIFACTID, ARTIFACT_ID}` but can't understand how to leave only the valid values

my question is: is there is a way to select field out of possible fields in `jq` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `select` expression with a boolean condition

```
.Components | map(select(.ARTIFACTID or .ARTIFACT_ID))
```

Doing `{ARTIFACTID, ARTIFACT_ID}` requires either of the keys to be present in the resultant object. So if either of the keys are not present they are updated with `null`. Using `select` clause evaluates the expression and produces the result into the object only if it evaluates to true

[jqplay - demo](https://jqplay.org/s/DlnwgUyXNE)